# C - Splitting a user input up into tokens and identify/format them in output

Tags: c

Ok so my question to clarify is, a user input, i.e.
"Hey there 5 buddy 3.15 tonight 65"

I need to split this string up into tokens using a space delimiter, which i can do fine. My issue is on the 3.15, where im stuck is, in my assignment its declared that if its not an integer i must identify it as a string and output the result which would look like this.

"str str int str str str int"

as 5 and 65 are the only integers.

right now im doing it like this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char arr[66];
    char *tokens[10];
    int counter = 0;
    char *ptr = strtok(arr, " \n");

    while(ptr != NULL){
        tokens[i++] = ptr;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
         if(!isdigit(*tokens[i])){
              printf("str");
         }else{
              printf("int");
         }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

my issue is that the isdigit function thinks that 3.14 is and integer, do i need to use a modifier or something to make it identify as a str?

Comment: ive also tried it like if(!isdigit(*tokens[i])) || *tokens[i] % 1 != 0)

Comment: isdigit works on a single character

Comment: you are just checking the first digit of every token

Comment: To detect if a string is an `int`, perhaps call a helper function that uses `strtol()`?

Comment: i'm afraid isdigit() only checked the first character of the token.

Comment: "right now im doing it like this:"  Hmmm, code does not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isdigit(*tokens[i])` only looks at the first character, not the entire token/string.

---

To detect if a token is an integer, form a simple helper function.  Adjust as needed.

```
// Look for an optional sign, at least 1 digit and then a null character.
int IsInteger(const char *s) {
  if (*s == '+' || *s == '-') s++;
  int digit_found = false;
  while (isdigit((unsigned char) *s) {
    s++; 
    digit_found = 1;
  }
  // end with null character?
  return *s == '\0' && digit_found;
}
```

Could instead use `strtol()`, etc.

```
int IsInteger(const char *s) {
  char *endptr;
  strtol(s, &endptr, 10);  // no need to save result, just need to detect conversion.
  return s != endptr && *endptr == '\0';
}
```

...

```
for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++){
  if(IsInteger(tokens[i])) {
    printf("str");
  } else{
    printf("int");
  }
}
```

---

Also, increment `counter`, not `i`.

```
while(ptr != NULL){
    // tokens[i++] = ptr;
    tokens[counter++] = ptr;
    ptr = strtok(NULL, " \n");
}
```